# Visual Studio Release and Debug difference

Tags: c++, opencv, floating-point, release-mode, debug-mode

I'm writing a code in which I read and image and process it and get a `Mat of double/float`. I'm saving it to a file and later on, I'm reading it from that file.

When I use double, the space it requires is 8MB for 1Kx1K image, when I use float it is 4MB. So I want to use `float`.

Here is my code and output:

```
Mat data = readFloatFile("file_location");
cout << data.at<float>(0,0) << "   " <<  data.at<double>(0,0);
```

When I run this code in the `DEBUG mode`, the print out for float is `-0` and **double gives exception namely `assertion failed`**. But when I use `RELEASE mode` the print out for float is `-0` and **0.832 for double which is true value**.

My question is why I cant get output when I use `data.at<float>(0,0)` and why I don't get exception when I use `data.at<double>(0,0) in RELEASE mode` which is supposed to be the case?

**EDIT**: Here is my code which writes and reads

```
void writeNoiseFloat(string imageName,string fingerprintname) throw(){

    Mat noise = getNoise(imageName);

    FILE* fp = fopen(fingerprintname.c_str(),"wb");
    if (!fp){
        cout << "not found ";
        perror("fopen");
    }
    float *buffer = new float[noise.cols];
    for(int i=0;i<noise.rows;++i){
        for(int j=0;j<noise.cols;++j)
            buffer[j]=noise.at<float>(i,j);     
        fwrite(buffer,sizeof(float),noise.cols,fp);
    }

    fclose(fp);
    free(buffer);
}   

void readNoiseFloat(string fpath,Mat& data){
    clock_t start = clock();
    cout << fpath << endl;
    FILE* fp = fopen(fpath.c_str(),"rb");
    if (!fp)perror("fopen");
    int size = 1024;
    data.create(size,size,CV_32F);

    float* buffer= new float[size];
    for(int i=0;i<size;++i)   {
        fread(buffer,sizeof(float),size,fp);
        for(int j=0;j<size;++j){
            data.at<float>(i,j)=buffer[j];
            cout << data.at<float>(i,j) << " " ;
            cout << data.at<double>(i,j);
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Add the `readFloatFile()` code.

Comment: I added both read and write code

Answer (score 1):

The first of all, you can not use the `float` and `double` in one `cv::Mat` as storage itself is only array of bytes. Size of this array will be different for matrix of `float` and matrix of `double`.

So, you have to decide what you are using.

Essentially, `data.at<type>(x,y)` is equivalent to `(type*)data_ptr[x][y]` (note this is not exact code, its purpose is to show what is happening)

**EDIT:**
On the basis of code you added you are creating matrix of `CV_32F` this means that you must use `float` to write and read and element. Using of double causes **reinterpretation** of value and will definitely give you an incorrect result.

Regarding to assertion, I am sure that inside the `cv::MAT::at<class T>` there is a kind of following code:

```
assert(sizeof<T>==this.getDepth());
```

Usually asserts are compiled only in `DEBUG` mode, so that's why you do not give this error in `RELEASE`.

**EDIT2:**
Not regarding to issue, but never use `free()` with `new` or `delete` with `malloc()`. The result can be a hardly debugging issue.

So please use `delete[]` for buffer.

Comment: I know that I have to choose, and I have chosen float and coded accordingly but I forgot double part somewhere in the code and find out this thing.

Comment: @smttsp assert is not compiled in release mode.

Comment: I see, due to that it didn't give error. I tried for <uchar> it also didnt give any exception. How about my error? Do you have any idea about what is it causes me to get exception?

Comment: (correction) Not exception, it should have been wrong result when I use `float`

Comment: @smttsp I think, you should check the `buffer` first of all.

Comment: Is it possible that it is related to buffer size? in this code, I'm giving buffer size as 1024, may it be related. I mean, something like buffer overflow etc.(just guessing). I gave different values to buffer size but nothing changed(maybe I couldn't find the right value). Could it be related?

Comment: @smttsp you can try to use statically allocated array as a buffer.

Answer (score 0):

**Difference between debug & release:**

There's a bug in your code. It just doesn't show up in Release mode. That is what the debugger is for. Debugger tells you if there's any bug/issue with the code, Release just runs through it...
Also the compiler optimizes your code to run faster and is therefore smaller, the debugger uses more size on your HD because you can actually DEBUG it.

Release initializes your un-initialized variables to 0. This may vary on different compilers.

Comment: Thanks for explanation, I have added the read/write code, could you please check where is the error?